# Subject as Observable

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Для чего к Subject применяют метод asObservable? Subject ведь самодостаточный, может быть и observer-ом и observable. Два примера ниже работают одинаково.

```
// пример1

let currentUserSubject$ = new Subject();
let currentUser$ = currentUserSubject$.asObservable();

currentUserSubject$.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});

currentUserSubject$.next('hello');

// пример2

let currentUserSubject$ = new Subject();

currentUserSubject$.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});

currentUserSubject$.next('hello');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инкапсуляция. И чтобы кто-то не смог сделать в своём коде вот так:

```
function doSmth(user$: Observable<User>) {
  (user$ as any).next(new User())
}
```

Но я бы не заморачивался и оставил бы `Subject`.

Comment: я неуверен, но разве pipe async работает с Subject?

Comment: @Adrug, а почему нет?

Comment: Посмотрел исходники пайпа, там проверка наличия функции subscribe

Comment: @Adrug удивлю тебя - async pipe даже с промисами работает и с любыми объектами, сигнатура которых содержит метод `subscribe`

Comment: Так это и написал

Comment: @overthesanity, откуда у промисов subscribe?

Comment: @Qwertiy а причем тут subscribe? `The AsyncPipe accepts a Promise or Observable as input and subscribes to the input automatically, eventually returning the emitted values.`

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3f6bf6dfd166b994f6e99dc99f15a34cf833f8cf/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L121

Comment: @overthesanity, при том, что ты написал: _"сигнатура которых содержит метод subscribe"_

Comment: @Qwertiy там написано "_с промисами работает и с любыми объектами, сигнатура которых содержит метод subscribe_", если б у промиса был subscribe - то не было б смысла его выделять в предложении :)

Comment: @overthesanity, а, ну значит я неправильно тебя понял. Тогда да, верно.